# web2py: global name 'crud' is not defined

Tags: python, web2py

I am currently following a web2py tutorial and I am asked to append to my controls/default.py:

```
def entry_post():
"""returns a form where the can entry a post"""
form = crud.create(db.post)
return dict(form=form)
```

Which is fine but if I try to go to: mywebsite/app/default/entry_post I get a ticket error:
 global name 'crud' is not defined

Now, I've read the web2py documentation and I know that crud.create(db.table) is a valid syntax, so why does this happen?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Because you need to define a variable called `crud`. Do you have `crud = something` earlier in your program? Also, is the actual program correctly indented (it isn't in your post)?

Comment: It was indentent but there was a typo in the import which I didn't see (important without the capital for 'Crud').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BTW. Crud is an old API which we no longer support.

```
form = crud.create(db.post)
```

should be rewritten as

```
form = SQLFORM(db.post).process()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I solved the problem and get along (it was a typo in the import from gluon.tools)
I'll avoid using it if the support is ended, however in the official manual is encouraged, but that may be because is the 5th edition (which is in the official link, even though the 6th should be completed)

Thank you for your time and for developing the software.

Manuel

Answer (score 0):

[`Crud`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#CRUD) must be imported and instantiated:

```
from gluon.tools import Crud
crud = Crud(db)
```

This is often done in a model file so it will be available in any controller.